# Stopping Glaciers and Colonizing a Super Antarctica

Tags: colonization, megastructures, ice

In my World , an Antarctic-like region is slowly growing, as the world gets colder and glaciers from the north expand , destroying all structures in its wake. Even worse , the glacier creeps at an astounding 60 meters per day towards Ilu-Gusu , a large city with a population of 12.8 million only 240 miles away. Due to this , the Government of the Pan Human Empire has started a program to conquer the region. Its primary goals are to -

A) Reverse ( or at the very least , halt ) The glacier's expansion

&

B) Set up a permanent Human Settlement deep within the region , because , you know , reasons

The Ice "Super-Antarctica" is much like our Antarctic except much , MUCH larger ( about 370,000,000 square miles )

So my Question is : how could this possibly be done , if at all?

A Few things to Note

- My world is an infinite plane
- This Pan Human Empire has fully modern technology
- The empire has the Industrial might to produce Structure , Machine , or Object as long as it can be accomplished with modern technology

Comment: This is a small thing to ask. In providing figures for what is happening, please keep the units consistent. The glacier moves at 60 metres/day (metric), then the rest of measurements are Imperial. Metric is preferred international standard. By the way, the glacier will reach Ilu-Gusu in 17.8 years. Enough time to beat hasty retreat.

Comment: Something I can't comprehend. Your world is an infinite plane. Yet it's getting colder and glaciers in the north are expanding. An infinite plane won't have climate patterns like a globular planet. How can there localized cold places like a super-Antarctica? Wouldn't the whole world be as cold as its super-Antarctica? What is the source of heat like the Sun for an infinite plane? How can there be hot & cold places?

Comment: Antarctica is in the South, but the glaciers from the North are expanding?  How does North and South work on this infinite plane world work?  Sorry if this is a dumb question.

Comment: @a4android All climate related effects are do to an over-concentration of Handwavium in the world

Comment: I guess anything is possible if your world is an infinite plane. Therefore, build a tropical climate handwavium collector & turn super-Antarctica into the balmy tropics.

Comment: @a4android As stated , the empire is limited to that which modern technology can do. Simply put ; the world is limitless ,the people are not.

Comment: Sorry I exceeded the question's brief. I should be more focused. Infinity can be so distracting. Time to see if I can think of something. No guarantees, mind you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quite simple: induce global warming.

If your society has the technology we do today, it's very simple to synthesise super-greenhouse gases and/or create them as a by product (like we do today).

Here are a list of common greenhouse gases:

- Carbon dioxide (CO2)
- Methane (CH4)
- Nitrous oxide (N2O)
- Ozone (O3)
- Water vapour (H2O)
- Sulfur hexaflouride (SF6) and other hexafluoride compounds
- Chlorofluorocarbons
  (CFCs)
- Perfluorocarbons (PFCs)

Releasing a large quantity of said greenhouse gases into the environment will bring the temperature up slowly over time. Care must be taken to ensure not to overdo it in order to prevent larger issues in the future due to overheating. Anthropogenic sources of global warming have a very high latency and require a long time to take effect on the climate. Additionally, do bear in mind the potential *other* undesirable effects of the gases you intend to release (for example CFCs break down ozone and cause holes in the ozone layer).

## ALSO

You state that your world is an infinite plane, but one crucial problem with that is the lack of polar regions for colder environments. I'd go a little more in detail here about how polar regions are dependent on having a sphere rotate at an axis angle (~23° for Earth IIRC), but that might be out of the scope of this question. Of course, a little bit of hand-waving here and there and problem solved.